# Google restriction on keyword monitoring tool

Tags: search, google-api, search-engine, google-search

We are developing a tool to track keyword positions and comparison graphs ( time series ), something like serps.com. But our main challenge is to avoid being ban by Google. Our tool is not commercial right now but maybe one day we are going to make it public and earn money from it. We have a common question :

-How we can get permission from Google to be authorized to have this tool, even if we have to pay Google for keyword ranks ?

Answer (score 0):

It's against [Google's terms of service](https://www.google.com/policies/terms/archive/20070416-20120301/) (see section 5.3).

Commercial rank trackers have ways around this, which boil down to not getting caught. I'll leave the specifics of how they do that to your ingenuity.

Comment: And that's the mystery part. How they can build up a commercial one. You can join our group if you have a solution.

Comment: I know what the solution is — I used to work for a commercial rank tracker — I'm just not saying what it is ;)